# How to perform conditional check on nested JSON with JOI Validator

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

I have an `express` API and running `joi` validator as my middleware. I am struggling to figure out how to perform conditional checks on my nested JSON object.

I basically want `LocationData` to be `required` when `userSelection` is `Yes`. If `userSelection` is `No` and `LocationData` is sent, then it should give an error.
The other condition is, if `UserSelection` is `Yes` and `LocatoinData` is sent, I want to have all the data inside `LocationData` as required. You will notice, I made the `name`, `latitude` and `longitude` required provided that the `name` exists.

Here's my code below. The issue is that even with `userSelection` as `No`, it's still accepting the `LocationData` which is not supposed to happen.

Here's what I'm sending in my body:
"parent":{
"userSelection":"Yes",
"LocationData":{
"name":"Location Name",
"address":"Location Address",
"latitude":"-20.200202",
"longitude":"50.230230"
}
}

Below is the JOI Validation Schema:

```
let requiredIfExist = {
    is: Joi.exist(),
    then: Joi.required(),
    otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
};
parent: Joi.object().required().keys({
        userSelection: Joi.string().valid("Yes", "No").required(),
        LocationData: Joi.object().keys({
            name: Joi.string().min(3).max(100).when("userSelection", {
                is: "Yes",
                then: Joi.required(),
            }).concat(Joi.string().when("userSelection", {
                is: "No",
                then: Joi.forbidden(),
            })),
            address: Joi.string().when("name", requiredIfExist),
            latitude: Joi.number().min(-90).max(90).when("name",requiredIfExist),
            longitude: Joi.number().min(-180).max(180).when("name", requiredIfExist)
        }).concat(Joi.object().when("userSelection", {
            is: "No",
            then: Joi.forbidden(),
        })),
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need conditions everywhere. You can simplify your schema to just

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    parent: Joi.object().required().keys({
        userSelection: Joi.string().valid('Yes', 'No').required(),
        LocationData: Joi.object().keys({
            name: Joi.string().min(3).max(100).required(),
            address: Joi.string().required(),
            latitude: Joi.number().min(-90).max(90).required(),
            longitude: Joi.number().min(-180).max(180).required(),
        })
    }).when(Joi.ref('.'), {
        is: Joi.object().keys({
            userSelection: Joi.equal('Yes')
        }),
        then: Joi.object({
            LocationData: Joi.required()
        }),
        otherwise: Joi.object({
            LocationData: Joi.forbidden()
        })
    })
});
```

This schema checks:

1. If `userSelection` is `Yes` ----> `LocationData` is required with all fields
2. If `userSelection` is `No`  ----> `LocationData` is not allowed